# Actions for JSF outputLink

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF commandButton with a value and an action.

```
<h:commandButton id="btnSearch" value="#{SPP.fireStudyTitle}" action="#{searchBean.doMagic(SPP.acronym)}" immediate="true" onchange="submit();" 
    style="font-weight:bold; font-size:small;"  onclick="javascript:cursor_wait()" class="buttonsFEIS" />&#160;&#160;
```

Is there anyway I can do the exact same thing with an outputLink like the one below?

```
 <h:outputLink value="#{searchBean.doMagic(SPP.acronym)}">#{SPP.fireStudyTitle}</h:outputLink>
```

I'm getting this error when attempting to use the commandLink:

```
javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
```

If it's not possible, how would I go about changing the commandButton to look pretty much exactly like a commandLink?

Thanks.

Comment: @7SpecialGems-So, there's no real way to just make the OutputLink take an action and run it, the way a commandButton does?